# How to create a WPF Image from an RGB Color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, treeview

I have some colors for my `Layer` objects that are shown in a `TreeView`. Right now I use something like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="300">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Layers" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel MouseLeftButtonDown="Layers_MouseLeftButtonDown" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="15"
                        Height="15"
                        Source="{Binding ImageFromColor}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The original color values are gonna be accessed (binded) from the `Layer` itself, so like:

```
layer.Color
```

of type `System.Drawing.Color`. But I can change the type to be something else if it would make things easier.

What's the best way to do this in terms of performance and elegance?

I will have a couple thousand `TreeView` items it that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not try it myself with a TreeView (only with a ListBox), but maybe this is worth a try:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!-- your additional container -->
        <Canvas Width="15" Height="15">
             <Canvas.Background>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ColorProperty}" />
             </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    <!-- end of container -->
</DataTemplate>
```

This approach uses a direct binding to the color property, so no images need to be created (e.g. by a Converter).

But it is definitely recommended to try it out to see if it works with thousands of items.

Comment: Thanks but that ColorProperty, what type should it be? System.Drawing.Color? Also you used Canvas, that would be better than Image? Just wondering.

Comment: Yes, ColorProperty would be of type `System.Drawing.Color` and I suppose that `Canvas` (or any other simple visual control, even a Grid works) needs less resources than an image, because you would need to create a matching image in memory and even with caching this would take more resources than a simple control.

Comment: So Canvas would be lighter even than a Grid? I will use Canvas, just curious. Lastly do you know what event I can use to do something when the Canvas is clicked? I found MouseDown, so I guess that should work?

Comment: As `Canvas` and `Grid` are both derived from `Panel` there should be no great difference (at least they do not need any additional resources like an `Image` will need), but this is just a _good_ _guess_. There should be `MouseLeftButtonDown` but if you see `MouseDown` then that should work too.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Btw what's the difference between `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseDown`? I assume the latter provides all access whereas the first one only fires for left button down. But still one would fire before the other, right? Which one that would be?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right, and doing a little test it seems that `MouseLeftButtonDown` is likely to be fired before `MouseDown` which makes sense, because the latter one is more "generic". But I would not rely on this until verification in MSDN.